# Get value of each instance of class

Tags: jquery

For each instance of a class (`selected`) I need to get the value of the previous class (`imageID`).  The plan is to get the `imageID` value, trigger an ajax call and set the attribute of each instance of the class (`selected`) depending on the ajax response.

The code I have so far is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selected').each(function(){
    var image_id = $('.selected').prev('.imageID').val();
    alert(image_id);
   });
});
```

However, all this does is trigger an alert for each instance of `selected` but always with the value of the first instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.selected') // selects all the .selected elements 
    .prev('.imageID') // all very previous siblings that have `ImageId` class
    .val(); // as getter returns value of the first element in the set
```

Use the `this` keyword:

```
var image_id = $(this).prev('.imageID').val();
```